# Sum values from different objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, mongoose, sum

I am trying to sum values from different objects. Each object has its ID, but the IDs can repeat in some objects. What I need to do now is sum the values from the objects that have the same ID.

Does someone have an idea for me? I tried to use mongoose aggregate, but with no success.

**Let's suppose I have the objects below.**

```js
const array = [
  { _id: "123456", value: 30 },
  { _id: "123456789123456789", value: 12 },
  { _id: "123456", value: 25 },
];
```

**I would need something that brings up the following result:**

```
==>  id: 123456
     value: 55

==>  id: 123456789123456789
     value: 12
```

Comment: are the objects grouped inside an array?

Comment: Hello, yeah. Objects are grouped inside an array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971373/group-by-count-distinct-sum-totals-from-objects-in-javascript-array

Comment: Do you want to do this in javascript or with an aggregation pipeline and have the MongoDB server do it?  If you want to use a pipeline, would you show a few example documents from your collection?

Answer (score 1):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array into a map. Conveniently, `map.set` returns the map, so it's just a one-liner.

```js
const array = [{ _id: "123456", value: 30 }, { _id: "123456789123456789", value: 12 }, { _id: "123456", value: 25 }];

const sums = array.reduce((map, object) => map.set(object._id, map.get(object._id) ?? object.value), new Map());

console.log(sums.get("123456"));
console.log(sums.get("123456789123456789"));

// convert to normal object

const sumsAsNormalObject = Object.fromEntries([...sums.entries()]);

console.log(sumsAsNormalObject);
```

Confused about syntax? See [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can also convert the map into a plain object if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

its impossible to have duplicate _id  in mongodb, but you can change that to something like `dataId, id` or else

example:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    id: 123456,
    value: 30
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    id: 123456789123456789,
    value: 12
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    id: 123456,
    value: 25
  }
]
```

then with wongo would be like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "value": {
        "$sum": "$value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s0Zd402s69b)

Note: *if some data can be handle by resources/database, use it instead. otherwise, create a function to handle it.*

Answer (score 0):

For each object, it checks whether the **"result"** object already has a property with the same **_id** as the current object being looped over.

```js
    const array = [
      { _id: "123456", value: 30 },
      { _id: "123456789123456789", value: 12 },
      { _id: "123456", value: 25 },
    ];
    
    const result = {};
    
    array.forEach(item => {
      if(result[item._id]) {
        result[item._id] += item.value;
      } else {
        result[item._id] = item.value;
      }
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```